# MySQL INSERT with multidimensional php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write an INSERT SQL request to populate a table of my db with a multidimensional array.

The array use the session variables (it's a shopping cart) $_SESSION['panier'], and currently has the following content :

```
array (size=3)
  'ARTCOD' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'NA1818BLCFEZ' (length=12)
      1 => string 'SER5151BLCFEZ' (length=13)
  'COLLIB' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'blanc' (length=5)
      1 => string 'blanc' (length=5)
  'quantite' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 6
      1 => int '8'
```

My table has more field :
the 'ID' field, which need to auto increment.

the 'reference' field, which contains the reference of the order, I will generate it randomly.

The 'ARTCOD' field, it's the code associated to an article, here it's in $_SESSION['panier']['ARTCOD'].

The 'CLICOD' field, it's the code associated to the client which is ordering, here it's in $_SESSION['CLICOD'].

the 'quantite' field, the quantity of the ordered article, contained in $_SESSION['panier']['quantite'].

The 'type' field, contain the order type, here it's just a defined word that will not change.

And the 'date' field, contain the timestamp of the order.

So I need help to write a function that will generate my MySQL request without using multiple INSERT.

I've already create this:

```
$query = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['panier']['ARTCOD']); ++$i) {
    $query .= 'INSERT INTO commandevalide (id, reference, ARTCOD, CLICOD, quantite, type, date) VALUES ("", "'.$_SESSION['panier']['ARTCOD']['$i'].'", "'.$reference.'", "'.$_SESSION['CLICOD'].'", '.$_SESSION['panier']['quantite']['$i'].', "Location", now());';
}
```

But I prefer something which will give just one INSERT request.

I saw that I need to use the implode function and a foreach loop but I did not manage to create something working.

Comment: What database driver are you using? PDO? `mysqli`? Hopefully not the awful `mysql_query`.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: @tadman : I use Mysqli.

Comment: @Marc B : I edited my post, I just need help to write the function wich will generate the SQL request without using multiple INSERT

Comment: Can you give an example of some code using multiple insert? This will help us in determining how to optimize your code.

Comment: @Dave Chen : I edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine all those inserts into a single one, you can try this :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO commandevalide (id, reference, ARTCOD, CLICOD, quantite, type, date) VALUES ";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['panier']['ARTCOD']); ++$i) {
    $query .= '("", "'.$_SESSION['panier']['ARTCOD'][$i].'", "'.$reference.'", "'.$_SESSION['CLICOD'].'", '.$_SESSION['panier']['quantite'][$i].', "Location", now()), ';
}

$query = rtrim($query, ', ');
```

Note : Don't put `$i` between single quotes.

Comment: Great idea, that's working like a charm ! As we say here in france "Merci !" :)